# How do I find out which is clicked on my ActionBar MenuItem?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, click

How do I know if an item is clicked?

Since I understand if, say **event A** will occur following only an button of actionbar was clicked, how do I implement such a thing?

Comment: See.. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond

Comment: Yes, I know. I  have to do so that I can "record" when a button was clicked

Comment: @LeonardoShofflen Did you follow the ActionBar guide? Do you already have a ActionBar working in place? If so, the guide already tells you how: set onCreateOptionsMenu to make them appear in the ActionBar, then define your logic in onOptionsItemSelected to “record” when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are creating in the `onOptionsSelected(MenuItem item)` method works like an `OnClickListener` for buttons.

It asks for the id of the menu item trough the method `getItemId()` and then handles for each item the specific click. For example starting a SettingsActivity, when Settings from the menu was clicked

But check out the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond) of the comments for further information.

The code you need to implement it:

```
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

But this all can be found in the tutorial